12v motorcycle AGM battery
I have a pulse repair battery charger 12v and it's says it can only charge lead acid batteries, I also have an AGM battery in my motorcycle and wanted to know would the charger work on the AGM battery or do you need a special charger.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

While you could possibly use this charger on an AGM battery, I'd highly recommend against it. The main purpose of a pulse repair battery charger is to reduce/repair sulfation in a battery. While this can occur in an AGM battery, the likelihood of it happening is a lot less than in a regular flooded battery. Due to this, the pulse charger probably isn't going to do what it is intended to do. Secondly, if the charger says you shouldn't, it's probably a good idea you don't. If the charger has a pulse mode and a separate charging mode, I would be more inclined to suggest it might be okay. Regular battery chargers aren't the best for AGM, but will work. Realistically, you should be using a charger which has an AGM mode built into it.

Hi so would you say it would be better to use the charge setting and not the repair setting? Would it work just to use charge setting and charge it?

@RickMorty - I mean, you can do anything you want with your charger and batteries. If your charger does not have a specific AGM mode, I'd get one which does.
